# Collect Gradle project's dependency constraints

Tags: gradle, dependencies, constraints

I am looking for a way to collect all the dependency constraints (enforced with a regular `platform` and/or `enforcedPlatform` and/or "manually") for a given project from a custom Gradle plugin.

In Maven world, you can resolve an "artifact descriptor" that will give access to the effective list of all the managed dependencies enforced on the artifact. I couldn't find so far how this kind of info could be collected in Gradle.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

based on the clarification of the question - below can be a start (requires more work - for some reason my local shows configuration as default - not the compile/runtime)

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        configurations.findAll {it.canBeResolved==true}.each { println it + "\n" ; it.allDependencies.each { println it } }
    }
}
```

---

The question (appears to me) is sharing the test code across modules in a multi-module project

Short answer - No - there is direct test dependency share across modules.

To share test code between modules internally via build settings

**Official gradle route** https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures

**Simple hack**

`testImplementation files(project(':core-module').sourceSets.test.output.classesDirs)` 
add the above line either individually where you need or in root with subprojects() with appropriate condition

*there are other possible routes as well *
ex: via `configuration child.testImplementation extends parent.testImplementation` (or runtime)

Comment: Thanks @PrasadU, the question is not about that though. In other words, I want to get the effective set of all the platforms and enforcedPlatforms (if any) configured for the project. E.g. if a project includes `implementation enforcedPlatform("group:name:version")`, I want to collect all the dependency constraints enforced by that platform.

Comment: Thanks again, @PrasadU. IIUC, that will collect all the dependencies from all the resolvable configurations. What I am after is collecting all the enforcedPlatform dependencies and then simply reading their content. I am actually not interested in the actual project dependencies in this case. If we think of the enforced platform as a BOM, I want the content of the BOM. More specifically, I want the effective set of all the dependency constraints (managed deps) from all the BOMs enforced on a given project.